# Aggregating a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have this data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(time = seq(0.2,4,0.2), behavior = c(rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(0,4),rep(1,4)), n1 = rnorm(20), n2 = rnorm(20))
```

`df$time` are time slices (currently time slice = 0.2s).

I'm looking for an efficient function that given a time slice value - hence the grouping value is `df$time`, will aggregate the df accordingly by summing `df$n1`, `df$n2`,.. (in reality these columns go up to `df$n200` so I'm looking for something generic) and keep the maximum value of `df$behavior`.

For example, if time slice = 1.0 the resulting `data.frame` should be:

```
  time behavior         n1         n2
1    1        1  0.6995929  1.5603166
2    2        2  1.8677778  0.1046646
3    3        2 -1.5957459 -5.5116914
4    4        1 -1.0757102  1.5130076
```

Comment: df$time - just updated my original question accordingly

Comment: Your question boils down to how to `cut` the time values. Please show exactly, where you'd expect the cuts to be for different slice values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `dplyr`.  Here, the `values` for `n1` and `n2` are different as there was no `set.seed`

```
library(dplyr)
seq1 <-  with(df, seq(floor(min(time)), ceiling(max(time)+1), by=1))

grp <- group_by(df, time=cut(time, breaks=seq1, labels=FALSE))
df1 <- grp %>%
          summarise_each(funs(sum), n1:n2)

df2 <- grp %>% 
          summarise(behavior=max(behavior))

left_join(df2,df1, by='time')
#   time behavior         n1         n2
#1    1        1  0.8960162  0.6767968
#2    2        2 -2.2237071 -4.2431708
#3    3        2 -2.0750859 -3.7181187
#4    4        1  1.0824854 -0.2501264
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(behavior1=max(behavior),lapply(.SD, sum)),
    by=list(time=cut(time, breaks=seq1, labels=FALSE))][,behavior:=NULL][]
```

If you need to slice by `1.5`

```
 seq1 <-  with(df, seq(floor(min(time)), ceiling(max(time)+1), by= 1.5)
 grp <- group_by(df, time=cut(time, breaks=seq1))
```

and applying the above code gives

```
 #     time behavior       n1       n2
 #1 (0,1.5]        1 2.821384 2.981740
 #2 (1.5,3]        2 1.145459 5.962142
 #3 (3,4.5]        1 3.313462 2.236264
```

Comment: What if they want `slice = 1.5`?

Comment: I'm not sure. Thus, my comment to the OP above.